# Send UDP to local ipv4 address using local ipv6 socket

Tags: c++, sockets, ipv6, ipv4

I was wondering whether it is possible, on Ubuntu 12.04, to send an UDP packet from a socket with a local link IPv6 address to a device on the same wireless network using its IPv4 address. I have already succeeded in sending a UDP packet to that destination interface using its IPv6 address.

I have a socket with IPv6 address, IPv6ONLY not set:

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
int no = 0;
setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (char *)&no, sizeof(no));
bind(fd, (sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa));
```

I just send to a peer with sendto:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 peer = create_ipv6_sockaddr(55555, "193.156.108.67", 0, 0, true);
sendto(sock,content,strlen(content),0,(struct sockaddr*)&peer,sizeof(peer));
```

This function creates the sockaddr_in6:

```
sockaddr_in6 create_ipv6_sockaddr(int port, string addr, uint32_t flowinfo, uint32_t scope_id, bool ipv4=false) {
    struct sockaddr_in6 si;
    si.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    if (ipv4) {
        si.sin6_family = AF_INET;
    }
    si.sin6_port = htons(port);
    si.sin6_flowinfo = flowinfo; // Should be 0 or 'random' number to distinguish this flow
    if (ipv4) {
        addr = "::ffff:" + addr;
    }
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, addr.c_str(), &si.sin6_addr);
    if (!si.sin6_addr.s6_addr) {
        perror("Address is wrong..");
    }
    si.sin6_scope_id = scope_id;
    return si;
}
```

Basically if the address is a IPv4 address, I prepend it with `::ffff:`, and I set the family to AF_INET.

Is this possible to do. If so, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

To summarize, the IPv4 message cannot be send if the IPv6 socket is bound to a specific ip (or interface, not sure which). Therefore the IPv6 socket should use the wildcard `::0`. The family of the sockaddr_in6 struct should still be AF_INET6, with the prepended `::ffff:`. The code will not return failure if AF_INET4 is used, but in my experience no actual message is sent.

Indeed if instead of creating the sockaddr struct yourself, you get it from getaddrinfo, you will be able to pass it directly to a IPv6 wildcard socket to send.

EDIT YEARS LATER:

Per request, @Erfan, I dug up the code. I'm afraid to say that I no longer understand it all, and I cannot tell you whether it actually works.

```
sockaddr_in6 create_ipv6_sockaddr(int port, string addr, uint32_t flowinfo, uint32_t scope_id, bool ipv4=false) {
    struct sockaddr_in6 si;
    si.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    //  if (ipv4) {
    //      si.sin6_family = AF_INET;
    //  }
    si.sin6_port = htons(port);
    si.sin6_flowinfo = flowinfo; // Should be 0 or 'random' number to distinguish this flow
    if (ipv4) {
        addr = "::ffff:" + addr;
    }
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, addr.c_str(), &si.sin6_addr);
    if (!si.sin6_addr.s6_addr) {
        perror("Address is wrong..");
    }
    //  char s[40];
    //  inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(si.sin6_addr), s, sizeof(s));
    //  fprintf(stderr, "Sockaddr %d %s\n", si.sin6_family, s);
    si.sin6_scope_id = scope_id;
    if (scope_id == 0 && !ipv4) {
        si.sin6_scope_id = ipv6_to_scope_id(&si); // Interface number
    }
    return si;
}

int ipv6_to_scope_id(sockaddr_in6 *find) {
    struct ifaddrs *addrs, *iap;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *sa;
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];

    getifaddrs(&addrs);
    for (iap = addrs; iap != NULL; iap = iap->ifa_next) {
        if (iap->ifa_addr && (iap->ifa_flags & IFF_UP) && iap->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
            sa = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)(iap->ifa_addr);
            if (memcmp(&find->sin6_addr.s6_addr, &sa->sin6_addr.s6_addr, sizeof(sa->sin6_addr.s6_addr)) == 0) {
                getnameinfo(iap->ifa_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6), host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
                fprintf(stderr, "Found interface %s with scope %d\n", host, sa->sin6_scope_id);
                return sa->sin6_scope_id;
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(addrs);
    return 0;
}
```

And to bind:

```
int bind_ipv6 (sockaddr_in6 sa) {
    int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Creating socket failed");
    }
    char str[40];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(sa.sin6_addr), str, sizeof(str));
    //  fprintf(stderr, "Bind to %s:%d\n", str, ntohs(sa.sin6_port));
    int no = 0;
    if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (char *)&no, sizeof(no)) < 0 ) { // Only works with wildcard
        perror("V6ONLY failed");
    }
    if (bind(fd, (sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa)) < 0) {
        perror("Binding failed");
    }

    return fd;
}
```

Comment: there are examples of raw socket here : http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html. inet_pton is called with AF_INET in case of IPV4 in the udp6_to4.c example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `::ffff:` mapped addresses then you are actually sending IPv4 packets across the network while using IPv6 sockets in software. It makes it easier to support both protocols, but it doesn't allow you to mix the different address families.

The packet on the network is either an IPv4 packet (with IPv4 source and destination addresses) or an IPv6 packet (with IPv6 source and destination addresses). The `::ffff:` address will never be used in an actual packet. It only exists as a software representation.

If you use IPv6 sockets to communicate with `::ffff:` addresses then on the wire they will be plain IPv4 packets, and your local IPv4 address will be used on your side of the connection.

Comment: So I should still create a sockaddr_in6 struct, as I do now. Then the IPv6 socket will make it into a IPv4 packet with the local IPv4 address as source and the IPv4 destination address. So why do I still get a **Network is unreachable** error?

Comment: Try without `si.sin6_family = AF_INET;` and treat it like it is IPv6 from the software

Comment: that doesn't change anything I am afraid.

Comment: Oh, what are you putting in `sa`? If you bind to an IPv6 address then it can't send the packet from an IPv4 source address anymore. `IPV6_V6ONLY=0` only works when your local socket is bound to the wildcard address.

Comment: hi @Oxidator, could you please post the working code after the modification? I'm having the same problem in my app and I must say that I'm very nerd in case of these networking stuffs. Your help will make my life easier. Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: @Erfan I added the code that I could find. I hope it's helpful. I don't know whether it actually works. It's been a while since I have used it ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @Oxidator for the code. I will try this today and let you know. :)
Should I make some changes in the server side too? I have the server supporting ipv4 which was written years ago! :(

Comment: Also I didn't find the function implementation of "ipv6_to_scope_id(&si);"

Comment: @Erfan I added it too. My bad. Good luck :)

Comment: @Oxidator thanks again. But my bad luck it doesn't work. It cannot bind successfully and showing the following error: "Binding failed: Can't assign requested address" :(

Comment: @Erfan Sorry to hear that, but there is not much I can do. You might be better served by opening a new question. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, anyway, thank you so much for your help @Oxidator :)

Answer (score 0):

`::ffff:` addresses are only for usage in `IPV6_V6ONLY=0` server sockets.

If you want to connect to an IPv4 address, create a matching socket.

You can simplify your life if you just use `getaddrinfo()`: essentially, you put a host/port combination in and it will give you a list of "address entries" to connect to. These entries contain everything needed for creating and connecting a socket.

Here is a short code snippet as an example:

```
struct addrinfo hints = { .ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM, .ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME };
struct addrinfo * ai;
char name[100];
int sockfd = -1;
int st = getaddrinfo(host, sport, &hints, &ai);
if (st < 0) {
    // complain and exit
}
// Now we have the wanted infos in ai.
struct addrinfo * aii;
for (aii=ai; aii; aii=aii->ai_next) {
    /* Create a socket */
    if((sockfd = socket(aii->ai_family, aii->ai_socktype, aii->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        /* Establish a connection */
        if(connect(sockfd, aii->ai_addr, aii->ai_addrlen ) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            sockfd = -1;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            // Success. Get IP address connected to in a readable form.
            int st = getnameinfo(aii->ai_addr, aii->ai_addrlen, name, sizeof name,
                NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
            if (st != 0) name[0] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}
freeaddrinfo(ai);
```

Comment: I am curious. How is the first line of the code supposed to work?

Comment: @Oxidator The first line is an initializer for the given `struct` (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29#Struct_initialization) and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fstrin.htm)).

Comment: I really like the syntax, but my compiler doesn't for some reason.

Comment: @Oxidator Then you should change it: look up how `struct addrinfo` is defined on your system (or in general) and set the values appropriately. Or do `struct addrinfo hints = {}; hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM; hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;`. Or refrain from using an outdated compiler. ;-)

Comment: `struct addrinfo hints = { AI_CANONNAME, AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM };`, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo).

Comment: Oh.. I changed it. No problem.. Just wasn't familiar with this syntax.. At some point I will try to find out why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: That syntax can only be used in C and not in C++ as far as I understand, which explains it..:)

Comment: @Oxidator Oh, it was about C++ - didn't see that, sorry.